# how to get URL callback parameters in VUE js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i would like to ask how to get the url parameters from a external URL using VUE js?

for example I have page A which have a button to execute the call to the external URL. and then from that URL it will return a

> [www.example.com/?value1=example1%20value2=example2%20value3=example3](http://www.example.com/?value1=example1%20value2=example2%20value3=example3)

how can i get the ff:

value 1,2 and 3? how to save it in the instance of page A without showing it? and proceed to page B after value 1 2 and 3 is not empty?

thank you.

Comment: save the values from `this.$route.query.value1` in vuex/localStorage/bus and use `this.$router.push('/ur-new-route')` to navigate to new page and you can access localStorage here. eg. `localStorage.getItem('value1')`